# Submit form using webclient in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

I want to learn how to submit a form, from code behind passing a parameter.
Simple form: `testform.aspx` form

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="myname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
        onclick="Button1_Click1" />
</div>
</form>
```

`action.aspx` that will call the `testform.aspx`

```
    string testURL = "http://www...../testform1.aspx";
    string myParameter = "myname=bob";
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(testURL, myParameter);
    }
```

It is not working.

Am I missing anything?  When I check the value of `HtmlResult` in the debug mode, I see:

```
  <form method="post" action="testform1.aspx" id="form1">
 <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE0MDM4MzYxMjNkZIS41aWul6tldK7bcOjKW+U0EcsKsj2DW+D0GaLgyHOb" />
<div>
    <input name="myname" type="text" id="myname" />
    <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Button" id="Button1" />
</div>
</form>
```

There is no value in the `myname` attribute...why?

I tested the `testform.aspx` on its own and it works. On submit it saves the value to a file.

Comment: When you say it's not working, what do you mean.  Do you get an error?  What does the server receive?

Comment: @DWright what i meant the value in the parameter myname=bob does not get saved to the file. The value does not get passed to the testform.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should be pass the values using UploadValues

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{

    NameValueCollection vals = new NameValueCollection();
    vals.Add("myname", "bob");
    client.UploadValues("http://www...../testform1.aspx", vals);                
}
```

More information on the UploadValues method can be found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I tried it still the same. the value bob does not get saved to the file. does not get passed to the testform.aspx

Comment: Is it testform.aspx or testform1.aspx?

Comment: it is testform1.aspx sorry